# Доступ к рекламному аккаунту Facebook

Tags: post, facebook, facebook-api

Создал приложение в Facebook, настроил, получил токен доступа, сгенерировал долгоживущий токен. Пользователь администратор приложения и администратор рекламного аккаунта. Запрашиваю данные:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/act_7**********2/insights?level=account&fields=account_id,account_name,campaign_name,impressions,clicks,unique_clicks,reach,spend&access_token=EAA***********************************************ZD
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#273) This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the ad account. User is not admin on ad account 7**********2.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 273,
        "fbtrace_id": "B3******PP"
    }
}
```

Каких прав не хватает? Когда перехожу в рекламный кабинет по ссылке `https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/account_settings/information/?act=7**********2&pid=p1&page=account_settings&tab=account_information` перекидывает на адрес `https://business.facebook.com/ads/manager/account_settings/information/?act=7**********2&pid=p1&business_id=4************1&page=account_settings&tab=account_information` 
Может ли это как-то быть связано с доступом?

Answer (score 0):

Это может быть связано с тем, что ваш Ad аккаунт неактивен. Кроме того, если уровень доступа к Ad аккаунту находится в стадии разработки, то эти типы ошибок могут возникать.

Обновите аккаунт до базового или стандартного уровня доступа, тогда ошибка должна исчезнуть.